# How can I add a line break for every tilde found within the contents of several files found at a path?

Tags: powershell

I would like to use PowerShell to add a line break for every tilde it finds in a file.
The source could contain main .in files which contain tildes.

I have this script so far, and could benefit by some assistance in how to tweak it.

This will work for one file, but not for many:

```
 (Get-Content -Path '.\amalgamatedack.in') |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Replace('~', "~`r`n")} |
    Set-Content -Path '.\amalgamatedack.in'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) to find all your `.in` files, then follow the same logic, just replace the input and output hardcoded file name for the absolute path of each file ([`.FullName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname?view=net-7.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-fullname)).

Your code could also benefit by using [`Get-Content -Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3#-raw), assuming these files are not very big and they fit in memory, reading the content as single multi-line string is always faster.

```
# If you need to search recursively for the files use `-Recurse`
Get-ChildItem path\to\sourcefolder -Filter *.in | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw).Replace('~', "~`r`n") |
        Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: @ecuso glad it did :) happy to help